# SQL Server transform 3 lines with 3 columns in 9 columns one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    A.Id,
    A.NAME as Name,
    B.Rate as PayRate,
    C.Description as Currency
FROM 
    TABLEA A 
JOIN 
    TABLEB B ON A.id = B.TableAId
JOIN 
    TABLEC C ON B.Id = C.TableBId
WHERE 
    TABLEA.FieldX = 1
    AND TABLEB.FieldX = 3
```

This returns a result something like this:

```
Id      Name    PayRate     Currency
-------------------------------------
2503    John    110.00      Dollar
2503    Mike      5.00      EURO
2503    Erik     10.00      Dollar
2504    Rob       2.00      EURO
2504    Elis     11.00      Dollar
2505    May       4.00      Dollar
```

But I would like to return something like that:

```
Id      Name01  PayRate01 Currency01  Name02  PayRate02 Currency02  Name03  PayRate03   Currency03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2503    John    110.00    Dollar      Mike     5.00     EURO        Erik    10.00       Dollar
2504    Rob       2.00    EURO        Elis    11.00     Dollar      Null    Null        Null
2505    May       4.00    Dollar      Null    Null      Null        Null    Null        Null
```

It is not fixed query, this is just an example is going to bring many records from the same ID. Some could have 1 line, 2 lines, 3 lines or more lines. So ever ID I want to split into 3 groups of columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `PIVOT` to achieve this result. Please see [PIVOT Example from documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017#complex-pivot-example). Something like below...

```
SELECT id, [0] AS Name01, [1] AS Name02, [2] AS Name03
FROM   
(SELECT id, name
FROM table) p  
PIVOT  
(  
name 
FOR id IN  
( [0], [1], [2] )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.id;
```

If the data is fixed then one way to do that is to use `case` statements like below.

```
Select 
id, 
max(case when name='John' then payrate else null end) PayRate01,
max(case when name='John' then currency else null end) Currency01,
max(case when name='John' then name else null end) Name01,
max(case when name='Mike' then payrate else null end) PayRate02,
...
...
from table
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then payrate end) as payrate_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then currency end) as currency_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then payrate end) as payrate_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then currency end) as currency_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then payrate end) as payrate_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then currency end) as currency_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```